# Square matrix allocation using nested vectors dynamically

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, 2d

```
int n=0,b;
cin>>n;
vector <vector<int>> a;
for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
       cin>>b;
        a[i][j].push_back(b);
    }
```

help me to initialize 2d array with the help of vectors

Comment: Why do you shout?

Comment: There is no array.

Comment: BTW, typing in ALL CAPS is considered shouting.

Comment: sorry didn't know..can you suggest a way

Comment: Can you post a minimal working example, so that we can compile it? (includes, int main etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `vector<vector<int>>`, this is not a 2 dimensional array, but a vector of vectors.

You will need to create a row vector then push the row vector into the outer vector:

```
vector<vector<int> > a;  
int b;  
for (unsigned int row = 0; row < n; ++row)
{
  vector<int> new_row;
  for (unsigned int colunm = 0; column < n; ++column)
  {
    cin >> b;
    new_row.push_back(b);
  }
  a.push_back(new_row);
}
```

You may be able to use `[][]` if you reserve space when you create the vectors.

Comment: @NathanOliver:  Yes, that syntax can be used and the OP won't need a `push_back`.  I was keying off the `push_back` in the OP's code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you actually want something like:

```
vector <vector<int>> a;
for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    a.push_back(vector<int>());
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
       cin>>b;
        a.at(i).push_back(b);
    }
}
```

Note that for each row (outer loop), we first push an empty vector for that row and then push back to that new vector.